# How to hide api key using php proxy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've built a page that displays the current weather. It works.  But before I published it, I realized I need to hide the api key somehow. So I'm using jquery ajax to send a post request to a php file which will be located in a secured folder on the web server.  The php file will then send a get request withe api key added, and return the weather data back to the js script and render it to the page.  I've hacked together something I thought would work, but I think the php script is not receiving any data whatsoever from the post request. I've tried var_dump on the $_POST variable and the $REQUEST variable. All i get is an empty array. The js script logs what seems like an array back from the php script but I think it's just the js making an array out of the string it's sending? Besides I've commented out the statement in the php script that returns anything. Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong here?  I've posted the php, js, and html below. Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">



<style>
body {

  background: black;


}
.top-buffer {
  margin-top:200px;
  padding:0;

  clear: both;
}
.bottom-buffer {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">


      <div class="card text-center">
<div class="card-header" id="button-header">
  <button id="celsius" class="btn btn-light float-md-right">&#x2103</button>
  <button id="fahrenheit" class="btn btn-dark float-md-right">&#x2109</button>

        </div>

        <div class="card-body" id="weather-card"> 

            <h3 id="location" class="card-title"></h3>
            <h1 id="temp"><sup>&#x2109</sup></h1>
            <h1 id="description"></h1>
            <img src="", alt="" id="weather-icon">


        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

 </div>
    </div> 

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->

    <script src="script.js">    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

```
     var weatherAPI = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";

     function getWeather(pos) {

var dataString="lat=" + pos.coords.latitude+"&lon=" + pos.coords.longitude;
console.log(dataString);

$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "getweatherdata.php",
data: dataString
//dataType:"text"

      })
       .done(function(data) {
          // alert("result: " + data);
          console.log("data: " + data);
        weather = data;
        //console.log(weather);

        var tempf=Math.floor(9/5*(weather.main.temp - 273.15)+32);
        var tempc=Math.floor(weather.main.temp - 273.15);
        $("#location").html(weather["name"]);
        $("#temp").prepend(tempf);
        $("#description").html(weather["weather"][0]["description"]);
        $("#weather-icon").html(weather["weather"][0]["description"]);
        $("#celsius").on("click", function() {
          $("#temp").html(tempc + '<sup>&#x2103</sup>');
          $("#celsius").removeClass("btn-light").addClass("btn-dark");
          $("#fahrenheit").removeClass("btn-dark").addClass("btn-light");


        });
        $("#fahrenheit").on("click", function() {
          $("#temp").html(tempf + '<sup>&#x2109</sup>');
          $("#celsius").removeClass("btn-dark").addClass("btn-light");
          $("#fahrenheit").removeClass("btn-light").addClass("btn-dark");



        });
        var weatherID = weather["weather"][0]["id"];
        switch (true) {
          case weatherID >= 200 && weatherID < 233: //thunderstorm
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID >= 300 && weatherID <= 321: //drizzle
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/09d@2x.png");
          break
          case weatherID >= 500 && weatherID <= 504: //light rain,moderate rain,heavy intensity rain,very heavy rain,extreme rain
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID == 511: //freezing rain
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/13d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID >= 520 && weatherID <= 531: //light intensity shower rain,shower rain,heavy intensity shower rain,ragged shower rain
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/09d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID >= 600 && weatherID <=622 : //snow
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/13d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID >= 701 && weatherID <= 781: //Atmosphere
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/50d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID == 800 : //clear sky
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID == 801: //few clouds
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/02d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID == 802: //scattered clouds
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03d@2x.png");
          break;
          case weatherID == 803 || weatherID == 804: //broken clouds,overcast clouds
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/04d@2x.png");
          break;


        }

      })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
      });    

 }

     $(document).ready(function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getWeather);      

    });
```

```
<?php

//$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
//$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

var_dump($_POST);

//Get event ID you want to request:
//$data = isset($_POST['lat']) ? $_POST['lon'] : FALSE;

//Exit if no ID provided:
/*  if (!$data) {
    exit('No ID Provided.');
}  */
//echo $test->data;
//$lon=$_POST["lon"];

//Set your token:
//$appid = '49a090f8fd32a555bd97635debc34855';

//Set url, %s will be replaced later:
//$url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?'. 'lat=' .$lat .'&lon='.$lon.'&appid='.$appid;

//Set url, pass in params:
//$request_uri = sprintf($url, $lat, $lon, $appid);

//Try to fetch:
//$response = file_get_contents($request_uri);

//Set content-type to application/json for the client to expect a JSON response:
//header('Content-type: application/json');

//Output the response and kill the scipt:
//exit($response);

// header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

//$api_key = 'xyz1234';
//$result = array('status'=>'Error','msg'=>'Invalid parameters');

//your code to sanitize and assign (Ajax) post variables to your PHP variables
//if invalid:   exit(json_encode($result));

//make API request with $api_key
//$url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' . $api_key . '&item=' . $item . '&qty=' . $qty;
/* $ch = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);  // identify as error if http status code >= 400
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);  // returns as string
$api_response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch) || curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200 ) :
    $result['msg'] = 'Item not found or unable to get data. ' . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit(json_encode($result));
endif;
curl_close($ch); */
//$decodedData = json_decode($api_response);
//print $url;
//check for success and do any server side manipulation of $decodedData

//$result['status'] = 'OK';
//$result['msg'] = '$decodedData';
//exit(json_encode($result));

?>
```

Comment: Check your browser dev tools.  Any errors on the console? Check the network tab, is the POST request really happening, is the `dataString` there and correct? Maybe the browser geolocation stuff is not working?  Does it work if you just hard code your position and call `getWeather(pos)` on document ready?

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The key was to place everything inside an if statement conditional on when the data came through, as there was a delay

```
if(isset($_POST['lat']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {

   $lat=$_POST['lat'];
   $lon=$_POST['lon'];
```